# Convert String to Number

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a string `'Q1-96'`.

I want to fetch the quarter number i.e 1 in this case.

I have used `to_number(substr('Q1-96',2,1),'9')`.

I want to insert this value in a column of datatype NUMBER.

But as I used `to_number(substr('Q1-96',2,1),'9')` I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

Is there any way to do this .

Comment: It should work even without the to_number just by using substr('Q1-96',2,1). What does your insert statement look like in it's entirety? Are you sure this is the value that produces the error?

Comment: Please show us the **complete** insert statement (**[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Hi everyone !! Sorry for the question . As I checked , in one field data was 'APR-16' which was causing the issue . All of you are right . without using to_number data should get inserted .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need to use `to_number`?

```
SQL> insert into tbl1 select substr('Q1-96',2,1) from dual;

SQL> select * from tbl1;

  NUM
  -----
  1
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply !! It was my mistake . It was actually a data issue in some field .